# creating our own coin - connection refused error

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, litecoin, testnet

We are trying to create our own currency.

We first started with testnet.

The aim is to generate a genesis block and testnet did it very well. However, although we had connection between two computers and we have "hashespersecond" value more than 0, the balance stays 0.

Then, instead of using a testnet, we used mainnet(we read some topics about testnet which claim that balance never increases in testnet)

In mainnet, we saw that a connection is established(by using getinfo). However, in our log file, we always see the error:

> connect() failed after `select(): Connection refused

We inspected the code and found out a variable called nRet. The value of the nRet is changed in getsockopt built-in function. We don't know why the value of nRet has changed(any value except 0 means an error in socket).

We changed the port numbers, even the port numbers we used in testnet. But it didn't work.

We don't have any idea about how to establish a connection between these 2 computers. Both testnet and mainnet didn't work and we are struggling with this issue. We are using SmallChange, a faster version of Litecoin.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `netstat -tan` on the machine you are having trouble connecting to and see if it has a correct listening socket.